# Documentation on Device Mapper ioctls?

Tags: linux, system-calls, dm-crypt, device-mapper, ioctl

In the [Red Hat documentation on Device Mapper](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/device_mapper.html), it reads:

> "the application interface to the Device Mapper is the ioctl system
>   call."

So far, I understand that the **ioctls** are sent to `/dev/mapper/control` (for *most* distributions), but it seems I will need to dig around the source code for [*dmsetup*](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=tools/dmsetup.c;h=fabb1830b09b5bf8d5e2f571c1db7a2ca8130686;hb=ca427a711a33b02264689dcfca4bc5e5d2f9434e), libdevmapper, or similar to understand how the ioctls actually work and how to use them.

Are there any books, lectures, or documentation that expand on this topic? Am I stuck parsing through complicated source code? Am I better off using libdevmapper instead of the ioctl system calls? The man page for ioctl is too general to be of much use in this case.

Comment: Googling "device mapper ioctl" comes up with [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/35077/), which seems quite readable and not really complicated. The corresponding file is `include/uapi/linux/dm-ioctl.h`. `Documentation/device-mapper` also exists. Or was the question "I don't understand what an ioctl is"? And what do you actually want to achieve? Understand how the kernel works?

Comment: @dirkt Yes, thank you. A newer source of dm-ioctl.h can be found [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=libdm/misc/dm-ioctl.h;h=cdb0c4c20f48b2ecf33c79058c2fe963f1e5843a;hb=ca427a711a33b02264689dcfca4bc5e5d2f9434e). My goal is to use ioctl's to create, destroy, and modify dm-crypt targets. To clarify, my question is how to go about learning to use the ioctl's to accomplish these goals. I understand the extent of what the header tells me, but how to _use_ the ioctls, including formatting and initializing the structs, correctly for each command, is not clear to me.

Comment: Actually the kernel source doesn't say much, unless you want to analyze the source of drivers/md/dm-ioctl.c
The documentation in include/uapi/linux/dm-ioctl.h only lists the DM_* ioctls and doesn't even show how to fill the struct dm_ioctl

In theory you can emulate dmsetup create testdm --table "0 12345678 crypt aes-xts-plain 01234567…1234 just in three ioctl (including ioctl(dev_mapper_control_fd, DM_VERSION…) but there is little docs about how tu fill the structure passed as the third argument.